# Where should polyfills be included for Durandal style views?

Tags: modernizr, durandal, polyfills

I primarily develop internal web apps where IE8 is still installed on many PC's as the primary web browser.  I'd like to include this HTML5 placeholder plolyfill, https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill, for all of my Durandal-based views.  What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no special consideration other than loading the polyfill to your SPA according to the instructions. Of course as this polyfill requires jQuery make sure that jQuery is loaded before including it.

e.g.

```
<head>
    ....
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="placeholder_polyfill.min.css">
    ...
    <script src="placeholder_polyfill.jquery.min.combo.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    ...
</head>
```